# Вытащить CSS стили

Tags: html, css

На сайте в таком формате указаны стили:

```
/min/?ver=2&b=ui/css&amp;f=theme.css,tipsy.css,font-awesome.min.css
```

У меня два вопроса:

1. Зачем так делать вообще? (как называется подобная запись)
2. Как их вытащить по одиночку?

Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если так сделать, браузер будет перезакачивать этот файл на каждой странице

Comment: обычный запрос, сервер по указанным параметрам отдает нужную версию css

Answer (score 1):

Генератор ( минификатор ) видимо отдает стили предварительно сжимая их.
попробуйте в урл по 1 передать `/min/?ver=2&b=ui/css&amp;f=theme.css` может отдаст по 1